# Reset all buttons and drop down lists

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create an order form. I want it so that when you select the button to print out your order to also have it reset all the selected buttons. For the sake of simplicity I have given an extremely simplified version of my actual order form:

Html:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="button">
    <input type="button" onclick="reset();"
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function reset(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
 }
```

My Problem is that when I click the button to reset the page, the checkboxes stay selected.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My Problem is that when I click the button to reset the page, the checkboxes stay selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just reset the for then use RESET button as bellow

```
<form id="myForm">
    //YOUR FORM ELEMENT EITHER CHECKBOX OR OTHERS
    <input type="reset" value='RESET'/>
</form>
```

Now there is no need to write any script code, type='reset' will automatic handle reset of all element inside your form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your HTML, the last input button is not closed properly

Here is working [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8frbgzng/3/)

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="button">
    <input type="button" onclick="reset();">
</form>
```

Javascript code

```
function reset(){
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an unbalanced tag in your html, also `input type='reset'` can be used to reset the form

```js
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="button">

  <input type="button" onclick="reset()" value="button reset">
   <!--Adding new input type -->
  <input type="reset" value="reset"> </form>
</form>
```